# gst-rtsp-server Live streaming is not working

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, rtsp, gst-launch-1.0

We are trying to achieve android device screen live streaming on gst-rtsp-server.

We are receiving the stream from android device using command:-

> gst-launch-1.0 fdsrc do-timestamp=true ! h264parse ! decodebin !
>   tcpserversink  host=127.0.0.1 port=4953

When we telnet to 4953 port we are able to receive data. 
Now we are launching gst-rtsp-server as follows :-

> ./test-launch "( tcpclientsrc host=127.0.0.1 port=4953 ! h264parse !
>   rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 )"

Getting following error Logs:-

```
0:00:22.257583995 25336       0x6db230 WARN               rtspmedia rtsp-media.c:2058:wait_preroll: failed to preroll pipeline
0:00:22.257633979 25336       0x6db230 WARN               rtspmedia rtsp-media.c:2264:gst_rtsp_media_prepare: failed to preroll pipeline
0:00:22.262315726 25336 0x7f0e20020f20 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2865:gst_base_src_loop:<tcpclientsrc0> error: Internal data flow error.
0:00:22.262358530 25336 0x7f0e20020f20 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2865:gst_base_src_loop:<tcpclientsrc0> error: streaming task paused, reason error (-5)
0:00:22.263406036 25336       0x6db230 ERROR             rtspclient rtsp-client.c:602:find_media: client 0x83b8a0: can't prepare media
0:00:22.263590122 25336       0x6db230 ERROR             rtspclient rtsp-client.c:1807:handle_describe_request: client 0x83b8a0: no media
```